# How to use updateOrCreate with hasMany relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

How to use `updateOrCreate` with `hasMany` relationship. For example I have first model `Code`:

```
class Code {
  public function item()
  {
     return $this->hasOne(UserItem::class, 'code_id')
  }
}
```

And for the nested relationship `UserItem`:

```
class UserItem {
  public function serials()
  {
     return $this->hasMany(ItemSerial::class, 'user_item_id', 'id');
  }
}
```

And I need to `updateOrCreate` values of `serials` relationship. I tried this:

```
   foreach ($data['item_serials'] as $serial) {
                $code->item->serials()->updateOrCreate([
                    'serial' => $serial
                ]);
    }
```

But this doesn't work how I need, because it changes both serial values to same value. This is how `serials` table looks like:

```
id  user_item_id  serial
1   1             lorem
2   1             ipsum
```

And then I recieve `request`:

```
'item_serials' =>
  array (
    0 => 'test1',
    1 => 'test2',
    2 => 'test3'
  ),
```

And with this request I want to update `serials` table like this:

```
id  user_item_id  serial
1   1             test1
2   1             test2
3   1             test3
```

I hope I explained understandably. How I should approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Update or create takes two arguments
1-updated data
2-condition
like

```
$flight = Flight::updateOrCreate(
['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
['price' => 99, 'discounted' => 1]
);
```

see the docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

Add an `array` as the first argument inside `updateOrCreate()`, it'll be used to retrieve/find an existing `serial` if it does update but if not then create it.

```
foreach ($data['item_serials'] as $serial) {
    $code->item->serials()->updateOrCreate(
         ['serial' => $serial],
         ['serial' => $serial]
    );
}
```